# Google Cloud Platform Bucket: serving content with custom domain over https

Tags: ssl, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have created a bucket, named `app.example.com`, and assigned DNS records to point to that bucket. Website (contents of the bucket) is available on `http://app.example.com`.

Now i need it to be served over https.

1. I have created load balancer

   - with "backend bucket", which is pointint to the `example.com` bucket. Option "Enable Cloud CDN" checked.
   - with "Host and path rules" options:

     - Hosts: `app.example.com
     - Paths: `/*`
     - Backends: pointing to the "backend bucket"
   - with "Frontend configuration": i've purchased ssl certificate from godaddy and added it here. I assume, if google has accepted it, then it means it was valid and formatted properly etc.

Still, content is served over http and if i'm trying to use https, browser complains about security.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've configured DNS such that an app.example.com CNAME record points to Cloud Storage. Instead, you need an app.example.com A record that points to your load balancer's IP address.