# Google Cloud Platform Bucket SSL Settings

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I think my problem is the same as this one: (sorry for the duplicate)

[Google Cloud Platform Bucket: serving content with custom domain over https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45559816/google-cloud-platform-bucket-serving-content-with-custom-domain-over-https)

But, here my settings.

First, I created a custom subdomain : cdn.domain.com to have a SSL certificat. (to use it after)

[image]

I created a bucket, named cdn.domain.com

I created a Cloud DNS and add a A record to point to my load balancer's IP

[image]

And here is my load balancer configuration:

Http and HTTPS (with my certificat)

[image]

1. **HTTPS certificat**

So, is that possible to help me to setting my CDN please ?

https://35.227.242.87/web/build/css/select2.min.css it is unsecure :/

2. **Change Google IP by my custom domain cdn.domain.com ?**

https://**cdn.domain.com**/web/build/css/select2.min.css is that possible ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The error reported is `35.227.242.87 uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for cdn.websurg.com`. But I see `cdn.websurg.com` maps to 216.239.36.21 (and a few others), not to 35.227.242.87, so I think that's (at least part of) your problem.

Comment: I agree with that but, Google give this IP address 35.227.242.87 and I can't change it...
And Google give this IP address 216.239.36.21 for the custom domain...
:'( 
Do you know if there is an another way to do that ?

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer of its own, not as an edit.

Comment: Ok, I did it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SOLVED] 2018-04-18

I did it. So, this is my configuration:

- 1 SSL certificat for my domain (cdn.domain.com)
  no custom domain in google cloud
- Added a load balancer with HTTP & HTTPS protocol and **static IP on my bucket storage**.
- changed my domain DNS (cdn.domain.com) to point to my load balancer static IP

It's done and it works, very easy :)